# Compiler not creating an executable

Tags: c++, g++

I was recompiling the existing source files but it is not able to create the executable though it file generated has execute permission

```
-rwxrwxr-x   1 ilvweb ilv      2949112 Jan 31 09:34 karny

$ file karny
karny: ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped
```

The command used for compilation

```
g++ -m64 -mcpu=v9  -DSUNOS -DNDEBUG -g -Wno-deprecated  -o karny    tkm.o THlm.o Connection.o Socket.o  ThLogger.o File.o TextFile.o File.o Timer.o lPlugin.o \
            -G -lm
```

Is there any option missing

If we have both gcc and g++ and the source written for g++ in order to recompile with gcc what could be done as the as the currently in this environment we can use only gcc

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? `g++` doesn't take a bare `-G` like you've got there.

Comment: it is g++ compiler Solaris 9 9/05 s9s_u8wos_05 SPARC

Comment: If you're asking if you can compile C++ source code with a C compiler like gcc, the answer is probably "no" (unless your C++ code is also valid C code).

Comment: @jjlin I meant to ask is the possibility of execution of C style cpp (.cc) code with gcc but would probably require code change I was trying to get some compiler option which identifies the cc code and executes

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/System-V-Options.html):

> 3.17.41 Options for System V
>
> These additional options are available on System V Release 4 for
>   compatibility with other compilers on those systems:
>
> -G
>       Create a shared object. It is recommended that -symbolic or -shared be used instead.
>
> [... snip ...]

Seeing as you're on (SysV-derived) Solaris, it would seem you're asking GCC to create a shared object. Is there a specific reason you have that -G?

Comment: Nope it was part of default Makefile hence started using it I found out that gcc g++ both are available in this environment and gcc works perfectly while g++ doesn't

Answer (score 1):

According to `file`, you made a shared object (which usually would be named `*.so`).

Comment: yeah that is my question is there anything wrong in the compilation option due to which it is not considering it as executable may be the order of object files ?

Comment: @AKS: Can you compile just a simple hello world type program `g++ -o hello hello.cpp`?  If so, then try compiling that with all your options.  Then add in your real files one at a time.

Comment: Nope it is not workiing since we have gcc and g++ and I am able to compile the code only with gcc The source is compatible with g++ but not gcc I have edited the question